# Error ordering a query using postgreSQL via parse-platform and parse-serve

Tags: php, postgresql, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a doubt about an error in the query with postgreSQL, when I do a select, giving an includekey in another one table, to sort by a data that is in this other table returns the error:

> No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need
> to add explicit type casts.

And on the server:

> error: Parse error:  error: operator does not exist: text -> unknown
> {"code":1,"stack":"Error: error: operator does not exist: text ->
> unknown\n

the code is like this:
->ascending("pessoa.nome");

#### Environment Details

- PHP Version: 7.3.29
- Parse PHP SDK Version: 1.6
- Parse-server: 4.10.2
- Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Could you please include the query just to be certain?

Comment: $pessoaQuery = Pessoa::query()
                ->containedIn('tipoCadastro', [TipoCadastro::EMITENTE['valor']]);

        $query = Empresa::query()
                ->equalTo("ativo", $ativo)
                ->equalTo('usuario', auth()->user())
                ->matchesQuery('pessoa', $pessoaQuery)
                ->includeKey('pessoa')
                ->ascending("pessoa.nome")
                ->skip($inicio)
                ->limit($limit);